# C# Explicit Operators and Inheritance

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I'm sure this is a stupid question, but why does the following code not call the explicit operator for the cast on the child class MyBool?

```
public class DataType
{
    public static explicit operator bool(DataType D)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static explicit operator DataType(bool B)
    {
        return new DataType();
    }
}

public class MyBool : DataType
{
    public bool Value;

    public MyBool()
    {
        Value = false;
    }

    public static explicit operator bool(MyBool B)
    {
        return B.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator MyBool(bool B)
    {
        return new MyBool() { Value = B };
    }
}
```

then:

```
List<DataType> Types = new List<DataType>();

Types.Add(new MyBool() { Value = true });
Types.Add(new MyBool() { Value = false });

foreach (DataType T in Types)
{
    bool Value = (bool)T;
    MessageBox.Show(Value.ToString());
}
```

Produces the output: false, false

Is my only option to write functions on each class to take the place of the explicit operator functions?

Comment: My question was "why does the following code not call the explicit operator...?" not "is this working properly?".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> why does the following code not call the explicit operator for the cast on the child class MyBool?

Because the operator functions are `static`, hence also non-`virtual` and thus their target is resolved at *compile time* rather than runtime. This is the expected behaviour.

If you want to have polymorphic conversion operators you can call virtual functions *inside* the operators:

```
public abstract class DataType
{
    public static explicit operator bool(DataType D)
    {
        return D.DoCastToBool();
    }

    public static explicit operator DataType(bool B)
    {
        // We haven’t got an instance of our class here.
        // You can use a factory method pattern to emulate virtual constructors.
    }

    protected abstract bool DoCastToBool();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Operators are *overloaded* rather than *overridden* - in other words, the choice about which implementation to use is made at *compile-time*. The compiler only knows about `T` as `DataType`, so it calls the operator in `DataType`.

One option would be to remove the operator from `MyBool`, but add a virtual method in `DataType`, allowing for polymorphic behaviour:

```
public class DataType
{
    public static explicit operator bool(DataType D)
    {
        // TODO: Decide how you want to handle null references
        return D.ToBoolean();
    }

    protected virtual bool ToBoolean()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyBool : DataType
{
    // ...

    protected override bool ToBoolean()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

Note that this *won't* work for the conversion from `bool` to a `DataType`, as in that case we don't have any information about which subtype of `DataType` you actually want to create.

(Side-note: your code would be easier to follow if you used the normal .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: Jon, has this always been the case in .NET versions? Or has there been a time when .NET searched inheritance hierarchies? I ask because a bug related to this seems to coincide with a project upgrade to newer .NET. The object in question is typed as 'object' at compile time, but the run-time type does have the operator defined. I highly doubt this is the case but it has been suggested...

Comment: @Sprague: No, it's always been the case.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a garbage solution for you:

replace: `bool Value = (bool)T;`

with: `bool Value = (bool)(T as MyBool);`